# error: command 'rpmbuild' failed

Tags: python, centos, redhat, rpm

I am trying to generate a RPM Package.

My SO is MACOS El Capitan and the RPM generation is performed from docker with Red Hat 6.

My User is root

My .rpmmacros file is:

`%__os_install_post    \
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress \
    %{!?__debug_package:/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip %{__strip}} \
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive %{__strip} \
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note %{__strip} %{__objdump} \
    /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-python-hardlink \
    %{!?__jar_repack:/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars} \
%{nil}`

and y get the next error:

`building RPMs
rpmbuild -bb --define _topdir $MY_PROJECT_PATH/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm --clean build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/SPECS/udo.spec
error: error creating temporary file /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.oYIK1K: Operation not permitted
error: Unable to open temp file.`

`RPM build errors:
    error creating temporary file /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.oYIK1K: Operation not permitted
    Unable to open temp file.`

Comment: 1. Your question belongs to another stack exchange site (Unix or SuperUser). 2. Anyway,  perform the operation as superuser (`sudo`)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Eli, but I am already performing the operation as super user (root). Anyway I did that with sudo but I obtained the same exit. ¿Any suggestions?

Comment: Do *not* build RPMs as root user. Once that is resolved, is `/var/tmp` a directory? If not, symlink it to `/tmp`.